# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) - While running Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am totally stuck due to below error.

I have referred many stack overflow links but could not solve the issue. I know its memory related issue but how can I solve it?

```
process:         studio [385]
Path:            /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier:      studio
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  studio [213]

Date/Time:       2016-07-21 13:05:26.407 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9
```

**Exception Details are here**

```
 Crashed Thread:  Unknown
 Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
 Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000008fe01030
```

**Model** 
      Model: iMac12,1, BootROM IM121.0047.B1F, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.71f22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this is due to Intel HAXM, My system does not meet the minimum criteria :(

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) could not installed.